# Not able to redirect on same page after using google login in joomla

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, google-api

I have a website in Joomla and I am using one of the module to integrate social (Fb & google) login in it. Now the problem is that after logging in from google, it redirects to home page of the website. I do not want this.
How do I make website stay on the page where it was before log in?
The module has redirect URI as 'website/?provider=google'

Answer (score 0):

Which page you want to redirect to? And which module are you using for login? These modules always have a "Redirect on success" input box that will redirect the user to a URL if logged in successfully.

If the module is always redirecting to /?provider=google (e.g. that link is hardcoded), then you can do an .htaccess redirect to redirect to the right place.